# Cross-browser Text-indenting

Tags: css

Is the a uniform cross-browser text-indenting technique ?

I use text-indenting to hide text and replace with images quite alot. I do something like the following: `text-indent: -30000px;`

But, on Chrone, IE, and Oprah the text is indented out so it's not visible but the width of the element is still as wide at the text.
Ordinarily, this would not be a problem except tah it looks one way on FF and entirely different on other browsers.

Comment: Uhh... that's not the "text-indenting" I had in mind when I clicked your question title.

Comment: ````````````````````````````````````` Oprah :)

Comment: You get a text indent, and you get a text indent, and you get a text indent.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to specify the width of the element as well.

If you're doing that and it's still not working, could you provide some sample code for us to take a look at?

Comment: Hi Jan, providing the CSS code would be difficult. But if you visit http://test5omniforce.co.uk/node/28 and inspect the "Room Capacities " table in Chrome and FF. The issue is the "Theatre, Classroom, Boardroom and Cabaret" headers. The differences are very clear in both browsers. Setting the with and block display in Chrome fixes it but upsets FF. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also use this technique at times to show images, but in all cases I'm also setting the width on the element to match the image swap. If you set the width you'll get consistent sizing of the block across most browsers * cough IE cough *.

If you're hiding the text but also need to rely on the width of the rendered text for spacing I'd question if you're using the right technique for that particular situation.

Comment: I think my problem is the element is a 'th' in a table 'thead'. I found that if I set the width and display it as a block, it works well in Chrome but breaks it in FF.